# How to query data from two tables and group by two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, datatables

I am using **SQL Server** and I have two huge tables containing all sorts of data. I would like to retrieve data on how many Latvian or Russian people live in each city.

The language column contains more than two languages but I would like to query only "Latvian" and "Russian"

Table1 (columns worth mentioning):

```
ID
ProjectID
Phone_nr
City
```

Table2 (Columns worth mentioning):

```
ID
ProjectID
Phone_nr
Language
```

I want the query to retrieve information something like this:

```
City1(RU) | Amount of Russians
City1(LT) | Amount of Latvians
City2(RU) | Amount of Russians
City2(LT) | Amount of Latvians
.. etc
```

Or something like this:

```
City1 | Amount of Russians | Amount of Latvians  | Total amount of people
City2 | Amount of Russians | Amount of Latvians  | Total amount of people
City3 | Amount of Russians | Amount of Latvians  | Total amount of people
.. etc
```

I am wondering what would be the best solution to this? Should I use `join` or `union` or a simple `select`?

I came up with a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT top 100 t.city, count(t.city) as 'Total amount of nr in city', count(*), l.language
FROM table1 l, table2 t
WHERE l.phone = t.phone and l.projectID = t.projektID
group by t.city, l.language
```

I believe the `where` clause is correct because both tables have phone numbers and Project IDs, it is important that the query selects with this where clause.
Unfortunately this doesn't quite work. It returns rows in this format:

```
City1 | Amount of y | total amount of numbers in this language
City1 | Amount of x | total amount of numbers in that language
```

It's close but it's not good enough. Note: I am using `select top 100` just for testing, I will select everything once I have the query done right.

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction? Thank you

Comment: Sample data and expect results will help us help you. Why dose your attempt also have a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` and a `DISTINCT` when it has a `GROUP BY`? `TOP` with a `GROUP BY` will mean than SQL Server is free to return what ever arbitrary rows it wants to. The `GROUP BY` *should* be returning distinct results already, which means the `DISTINCT` is either redundant, or there's a flaw in your `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using conditional aggregation -

```
SELECT t.city, 
count(case when l.language='Russians' then 1 end) as 'Amount of Russians',
count(case when l.language='Latvians' then 1 end) as 'Amount of Latvians',
count(*) as 'Total amount of nr in city'
FROM table1 l inner join table2 t
on l.phone = t.phone and l.projectID = t.projektID
group by t.city
```

Note: It's always best to use join explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, your solution worked. I like the use of cases, it makes the code easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The logic of @Fahmi is correct. There is one more approach of using SUM instead of COUNT. I am adding the same for additional option to consider.

```sql
SELECT t.city, 
SUM(case when l.language='Russians' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Amount of Russians',
SUM(case when l.language='Latvians' then 1  else 0 end) as 'Amount of Latvians',
count(*) as 'Total amount of nr in city'
FROM table1 l inner join table2 t
on l.phone = t.phone and l.projectID = t.projektID
group by t.city
```

Comment: Thank you for your approach, I will test it!